# forEach in Thymeleaf form not posting results

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the form:

```
<body>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${wrapper}" method="post">
        <tr th:each="w: ${wrapper.answers}">
            <td><input type="checkbox" th:value="${w.validWithNoun}"></td>
            <td th:text="${descriptor}"/>
            <td th:text="${w.noun}"/><br>
        </tr>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

But when I get to the post page, there are no results.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class AskController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String ask(Model model) throws OWLOntologyCreationException {
        Word word = AskUser.getWords().iterator().next();
        String descriptorLabel = word.getDescriptorLabel();
        Map<String, OWLNamedIndividual> askWords = word.getAskWords();

        List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String n : askWords.keySet()) {
            Answer a = new Answer(n);
            answers.add(a);
        }
        AnswerWrapper wrapper = new AnswerWrapper(answers);

        model.addAttribute("wrapper", wrapper);
        model.addAttribute("descriptor", descriptorLabel);

        return "default";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String askSubmit(@ModelAttribute AnswerWrapper wrapper) {
        System.out.println("RESULTS");
        for (Answer a : wrapper.getAnswers()) {
            System.out.println(a.getNoun());
            System.out.println(a.getValidWithNoun());
        }
        return "result";
    }
}
```

I put the print in to see what was going on, but there are no objects. There were two objects in the list on the original page.

The stack trace is

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at linguistics.AskController.askSubmit(AskController.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
...
```

Comment: Your `<input />`s need to either have a `name` attribute (that must correctly match what spring is expecting) or you need to be using `th:field`. See "[creating a form](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form)" in the Thymeleaf docs.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that I need a `th:field`, but the `w.validWithNoun` can't be found when I use it under that tag. Typically the field would look like: `th:field="*{validWithNoun}"` I believe.

Comment: `*{validWithNoun}` resolves to `${wrapper.validWithNoun}` which I don't think exists on your object.  This might do what you want: 1) change your `th:each` to `th:each="w, i: ${wrapper.answers}"` and 2) use: `th:field="*{answers[__${i.index}__].validWithNoun}"`.  I don't really understand your objects though.

Comment: the `validWithNoun` boolean is on the `answer` object contained by the `wrapper`. I was trying to find a way to associate each checkbox with each answer object contained by the wrapper. Turns out, an easier method is just to list the values of the answers in the wrappers and use that to update the objects back in the Java code. It would be nice if there was a way to update each object contained in the list, though.